# Loop copies cell in one destination cell instead of moving to the next

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to do the following:
In a range, find all the matching cells to a criteria and then copy another cell.

Till here all good, however the copied cells end up always in the same destination cell, instead of moving down one row.

[image]

```
Sub count()
Option Explicit

    Dim r As Range, i As Long, lastrow As Long, ro As Range, sh As Worksheet, cuweek As Range, myrange As Range
    'i = 6
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    'Set myrange = r.Offset(2, 0)

    Set CopyR = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(lastrow, "A").Offset(1, 0)

    Set cuweek = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("G5")
    Set sh = Sheets("Input")
    Set ro = sh.Range("B3:TC3")

    For Each r In ro
        Set myrange = r.Offset(2, 0)

        If WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(r) = cuweek Then
            'MsgBox (myrange)
            myrange.Copy Destination:=CopyR
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You are copying to `Copy` but you don't update the latter in your loop.

Comment: But is it `Copy` or `CopyR`? Use Option Explicit!

Comment: Oh sorry! It is CopyR

Comment: What do you mean by "updating in my loop"? I do not get why, even if I make the destination range in the last row and then offset, the loop keeps pasting in the same cell. I have tried to move it around... but no success :(

Comment: You define `CopyR` outside your loop and never update it. Why would it change?

Comment: Could you kindly show me in the code? I have tried to move the declared value in the loop, but nothing changes...

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, update the destination cell inside your loop (you can set it inside your loop too).

Strictly speaking I don't think you need the variable at all (or some of the others) but that is rather tangential.

```
Sub count()

Dim r As Range, i As Long, ro As Range, sh As Worksheet, cuweek As Range, myrange As Range

Set cuweek = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("G5")
Set sh = Sheets("Input")
Set ro = sh.Range("B3:TC3")

For Each r In ro
    Set myrange = r.Offset(2, 0)
    If WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(r) = cuweek Then
        Set CopyR = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.count, "A").end(xlup).Offset(1, 0)
        myrange.Copy Destination:=CopyR
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I understand, I did not know that! however, it still does not work.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? You need to do some debugging, step through your code.

Comment: I have shared a picture to support the explanation. What does not work is the fact that the loop keeps copying in the same cell, while I want it for every new match the code find to move down from the lastrow. does it help?

Comment: Bah I missed something completely, the `end(xlup)` - try it now.

Comment: Is it definitely the right sheet? Does it do it right the first time and then stop? Do you have other code in the workbook? Do you have any merged cells?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205669/discussion-between-g-tti-and-sjr).

Comment: Same! I do have one more question... what if I would like to copy only the value of "myrange"? I tried to put .value after the offset but gives me back an error

Comment: `copyr.value=myrange.value` instead of the copy/paste line.